# Unexpected token on assignment operator

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

Trying to transpile a javascript with babel/webpack fails on an "=" symbol.  Any ideas why this might happen would be greatly appriciated.

```html
import auth0 from './auth0-js'
import { AUTH_CONFIG } from './auth0-variables'


export default class AuthService
{
   auth0=new auth0.WebAuth({
      domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
      clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
      redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
      audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
      responseType: 'token id_token',
      scope: 'openid'
    })
}
```

So, in the example above, the `auth0=` part won't transpile with babel/webpack.

Comment: This is not valid javascript. What are you trying to do? Should you move that code in the constructor and assign it to the object?

Comment: The issue is that you don't know javascript `class` syntax - I would've expected to see `constructor() { this.auth0= ... your code ... }`

Comment: I tried that.  I was following the example here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login

Comment: @Josh, the example seems to be broken then - the fact that in `login` it refers to `this.auth0` suggests what I expected in my first comment

Comment: What is the error from webpack?

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't with your code - it's with the tutorial not being clear enough about what you need installed for it to compile. It's using the [experimental class fields syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), which is not supported by browsers yet, and currently requires [a Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) if you wish to use it.

If you look at [the `.babelrc` for the example code](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-vue-samples/blob/master/01-Login/.babelrc), you can see they're using the following presets:

```
"presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }],
    "stage-2"
],
```

The `stage-2` preset contains plugins for all proposed JavaScript features that are at Stage 2 or higher of the standardisation process - class fields are at Stage 3, so they're included.

Class fields are fairly safe to use, as they're very likely to be added to the spec in the next few years - that said, if you don't want to use experimental features, you can fall back on the standard ES2015 class syntax:

```
export default class AuthService {
    constructor() {
       this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
            domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
            clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
            redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
            audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
            responseType: 'token id_token',
            scope: 'openid'
       });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It's worth noting that the Babel team now recommends using the individual plugins over the stage presets - they plan to stop publishing the latter once Babel 7 releases. See [their blog post](http://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets) for the rationale behind this.